# Split bus panel that I dont understand

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

I'm trying to understand what is going on in my electrical panel. I do not have a main breaker in my panel, nor is there a separate main breaker upstream. However, it does not appear to follow what I have seen in other cases for a split bus. Everything I've seen seems to indicate that there would be a set of 12 slots at the top reserved for the "rule of six" panel and a separate "internal sub-panel" below behind one of the six breakers at the top.

Now, see my panel:
[image: Open panel]
[image: Panel labels]

It appears that the there are two breakers marked "Main," one of which is not in the top 12 slots. Two of those top twelve slots are empty. I'm just not sure what I'm working with here.

The reason for the question is another question, which is that I am looking to replace my oil heat with a heat pump which requires 2 additional circuits, a 60A and a 30A, plus add an additional circuit for an EV charger that's rated at 30A, and what do I need to do to accommodate? I've had one electrician tell me I need to increase my service from 200A to 400A, and another electrician tell me that's crazy, and that I could get away with it in this box but should probably replace it.

Comment: How many square feet is your house? Can you post clear photos of the labeling on the inside left of the box? (You may need to turn the power off and use an insulated tool to move wires out of the way to do so.)  Also, do you already have a heat pump picked out, and what's the nearest major city to where you live? (I'm asking because that sounds like an awfully large amount of aux heat for a heat pump.)  Last but not least: is your current oil burner forced-air or hydronic?

Comment: That is an odd configuration, I'd be popping out breakers so I could see splits in the bus and terminations for breakers 9/11 and 13/15. Probably not a good idea for a non-electrician to take on that task. Adding A/C and EV charging stations often trigger local jurisdictions requirements to do a service load calc before issuing a permit, and you will likely exceed 200A.

Comment: @NoSparksPlease -- double-split-bus configs aren't completely unheardof, but I would like to see more of the labeling if possible, yes.  I am questioning the monster toaster backup heat, too, myself...so many people get themselves into so much utterly unnecessary trouble that way....

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I agree, not unheard of, but still think they are odd, particularly with the second main being in the fourth position. I would want to understand the splits.

Comment: Let me see what I can answer. House is about 2200 sqft. Nearest major city is DC. Current oil burner is forced air. I had 3 separate companies give me multiple estimates for  the HVAC replacement and all of them included 15KW backup heating.

Comment: Have any of those companies run a Manual J HVAC load calculation on your house? Or are they just "rule of thumb"ing it?

Comment: Total side note out of curiosity: The stranded ground wire to the pole is untwisted to make it through the knock-out at the bottom. Is that to code? Is that an indicator of oversized wire or undersized conduit? I know that it does _not_ effect the flow of electrons in any way, it just looks very unusual.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel There was no Manaul J load calc run. I believe they're simply basing off of the size of the house and the existing equipment.

Comment: @FreeMan No, that's not untwisted, that's SE cable.  Neutral is a bunch of individual strands that encircle the 2 conductors.  At some point it has to be unwrapped just like that, and twisted into a "stranded wire" of sorts.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica thank you once again. #TIL

Comment: I used the NEC load calc to the best of my ability, and it spat out 250A, which now I feel more lost getting all of these different assessments.

Comment: OP, do you have a multimeter?  Are you able to turn off each of the breakers labeled main, one at a time, and see which other breakers lose power, and which don't?  I have a suspicion that breaker 9/11 may be backfeeding breaker 13/15, in which case, they would function identically in shutting off power to the bottom section of the panel.

Comment: @NateS. -- I seriously doubt that that would be the case given the the wiring in the panel I see

Comment: @MikeDeaven I'd ask your HVAC contractor to run a Manual J for you then; if they refuse, that's a good sign you should be looking for a different contractor

Comment: The NEC gives you two methods of calculating loads for an existing dwelling 220.16 Loads for additions to existing installations (A)(2) Dwelling units. Which tells you to recalculate all of the loads using the standard methods in 220.12 & 220.14. Also you can use the alternate method 220.83 Existing dwelling unit (A) Where additional Air-conditioning Equipment or Electric Space Heating Equipment Is To Be Installed. Give it a look or at least ask you contractors which calculations they are using.